# Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string (with fetchAll function)

Tags: php, sql

Hi

I'm getting this error while trying to execute a php arrangement:

> **Catchable fatal error:** Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in **/home/u722941258/public_html/cuenta/account/chat/index.php** on line **56**

The code of the file:

```php
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../../access/functions.php';
$user_index = new USER();

if(!$user_index->is_logged_in())  { $user_index->redirect('../../access/index.php'); }

$stmt = $user_index->runQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


$stmt = $user_index->runQuery("SELECT * FROM conversations WHERE user_id=:uid ORDER BY conversation_id ASC");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

```
Some HTML with no PHP
```

```php
<?php foreach( $result as $row_conv ) {
  echo "
    <a href='#chat_".$row_conv['conversation_id']."' type='button' class='list-group-item' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#chat_".$row_conv['conversation_id']."'>".$row_conv['conv_name']."</a>\n

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id='chat_".$row_conv['conversation_id']."' class='modal fade' role='dialog'>
      <div class='modal-dialog'>

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class='modal-content'>
          <div class='modal-header'>
            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
            <h4 class='modal-title'>Chat con ".$row_conv['conv_name']."</h4>
          </div>
          <div class='modal-body'> ".
          $stmt = $user_index->runQuery("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE user_id=:uid AND conversation_id=:conv_id ORDER BY message_id DESC");
          $stmt->bindParam(":uid",$_SESSION['userSession']);
          $stmt->bindParam(":conv_id",$row_conv['conversation_id']);
          $stmt->execute;
          $result_chat = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            foreach( $result_chat as $row_chat ) {
             print($row_chat['data']."/n");
           }

          " </div>
          <div class='modal-footer'>
            <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Cerrar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ";
} ?>
```

So, how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: What's on line 56? By the way, `->bindparam(...)` should be `->bindParam(...)`, unless it's a custom method. Also, you made `execute` as a property, it should be `$stmt->execute();`

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Line 56 corresponds to `$stmt = $user_index->runQuery("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE user_id=:uid AND conversation_id=:conv_id ORDER BY message_id DESC");`

And bindparam works as bindParam

Comment: What's on line 56? Dump `$_SESSION['userSession']` and `$row_conv['conversation_id']` to check if they actually have the value in the data type you require.

Comment: @BasitSaeed line 56 content is above, and those variables have the correct values, otherway the page will fail completly (I checked it right now)

Comment: Well which specific line of code is on line 56? Also, it should be `$stmt->execute()` instead of `$stmt->execute;`

Comment: @BasitSaeed the line 56 is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811675/catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-pdostatement-could-not-be-converted-to-st?noredirect=1#comment66914764_39811675 And it works with both variables, the result is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is all being added to a string almost definitely incorrectly, note the `.` after

```
<?php foreach( $result as $row_conv ) {
  echo "<HTML Code, bla bla bla>".
          $stmt = $user_index->runQuery("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE user_id=:uid AND conversation_id=:conv_id ORDER BY message_id DESC");
          $stmt->bindparam(":uid",$_SESSION['userSession']);
          $stmt->bindparam(":conv_id",$row_conv['conversation_id']);
          $stmt->execute;
          $result_chat = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            foreach( $result_chat as $row_chat ) {
             print($row_chat['data']."/n");
           }

          " 
     <HTML Code, bla bla bla>
  ";
} ?>
```

I assume you ment something like this:

```
<?php 
foreach( $result as $row_conv ) {
    echo "<HTML Code, bla bla bla>";

    $stmt = $user_index->runQuery("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE user_id=:uid AND conversation_id=:conv_id ORDER BY message_id DESC");
    $stmt->bindparam(":uid",$_SESSION['userSession']);
    $stmt->bindparam(":conv_id",$row_conv['conversation_id']);
    $stmt->execute;
    $result_chat = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach( $result_chat as $row_chat ) {
        print($row_chat['data']."/n");
    }

    echo "<HTML Code, bla bla bla>";
} 
?>
```

Comment: I'll be damned! Completely overlooked that.

Comment: @BasitSaeed It took me a while to see it

Comment: So, hoy can I fix the error? And that `.` must be there, or another error appears. I've updated the code in the question, the full code

Comment: See my assumption, the `.` should not be there if the code is ever to make sense.

Comment: @RiggsFolly if I don't add the `.`, I get this error: ```Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$stmt' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/u722941258/public_html/cuenta/account/chat/index.php on line 56```

Comment: Then show us more of the code, as you obviously have other error in your code

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly and the others, the problem was that f***** `.`, I changed to `;` and now works prefectly

Comment: @RiggsFolly *Good catch! :-)*

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XAMPP you need to make sure you have a version that can handle PDO statements.